# Can't get Products div align in Mobile View with CSS

Tags: wordpress, css, woocommerce

I am trying to fix mobile view for [ProductList](https://www.jetronics.ae/) on the main page with CSS. I couldn't get div work in mobile view as I chose to show two products in mobile view [image: here].

The live link will show all the properties for CSS and Div code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following CSS property exists in your theme's custom CSS box or stylesheet:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px)
.afaqahmad123 {
    margin-top: -73px;
}
```

Remove that and everything is as it should be.

Hope this helps.